# Traveling with a photocopy of a European ID across Europe

Tags: europe, identity-cards

Is it allowed/accepted to travel with a photocopy of an ID (in order not to lose the real one) rather than the ID itself or would it create issues with the local police in case of checks? I mean, do they have some sorts of verification system or database checking in order to see whether the data displayed on the photocopy are authentic or not, since the same issue can come up with the real ID itself?

Sorry, I forgot to mention some crucial details.
I didn't mean traveling by plane, but I mean simple border crossings and coming backs (e.g Netherlands-Belgium or France-Luxembourg).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No.

Official ID documents have many features to prevent forgery or manipulation. They might also be officially invalidated when a new one is issued before the expiry date. A copy has none of those -- it might easily be photoshopped.

The **only** use for a photocopy or digital scan is as a handy reference of all the relevant data, in case the original gets lost. That way you have the document number when you file the report.

What you **can** do is get yourself both an ID card and a passport if your country issues cards, and take one or the other within Europe.

---

*Follow-Up:* Just to clarify, EU countries are **not** in the habit of arresting people just because they don't have ID on them. In fact, many don't require citizens to carry IDs. But anyone could get into a situation where the authorities want to record the ID of all involved persons and take official statements later. For those who can show ID, no problem. For those without it, there could be inconvenience.

And the sort of EU-wide automatic database query which the OP envisions doesn't exist. Authorities in one member state can send questions to another, but that takes time.

Comment: Ok thank you, but what if I get caught with only a photocopy?

Comment: @abdul the consequences of being caught with only a photocopy will be different in different jurisdictions and in different circumstances even in the same jurisdiction.  If you want to know about that, you can ask a new question.

Comment: @abdul, worst case, you are held by the police until your identity and immigration status can be confirmed.

Comment: And how can they confirm that? Would they contact the municipality that issues IDs like the one I'd be showinh in the photocopy?

Comment: @abdul, all I can say is that government agencies would talk to government agencies. And that might take time.

Comment: How much time? Two hours, two days, two months??

Comment: @abdul, that's impossible to say. I *doubt* that many EU states would take two months to confirm an identity, but two days sound possible. Imagine you are caught in a traffic violation on a Friday at 1800. Most offices have closed for the weekend ...

Comment: I wouldn't be using a car because I don't like them and I don't need them anyway.

Comment: @abdul, that was an example, and pedestrians can get into traffic violations as well. If you are so worried about the loss of the ID, get a passport and keep that safe at home.

Comment: @abdul If you are caught with only a photocopy you will probably be treated as if you had no ID. If you try to persuade them that they should treat the photocopy as a valid ID they will either ignore you or contact the issuing authority. If (to take an example) it turned out that the authority had not actually issued such an ID you would probably be arrested for fraud.

Comment: If they contact the issuing authority there would be no problem...unless they make a mistake and make me go to jail.

Comment: The thing is that when I get an ID search here in Italy, police looks into a database by putting all the ID data in order to check whether such identity really exists (fraudsters nowadays are very handy), so if they do this with a real ID then there's no real need to carry out a real one, moreover it's actually a gain, coz at least there's no risk to lose the real one and at the same time the data are crucial, not the ID itself.

Comment: @abdul, what would keep criminals from knowing the name, date of birth and place of birth of a real person?

Comment: I don't know what you're implying, explain further.

Comment: Knowing the information is trivial. Having _an original document_ itself, as explained in @o.m.'s Answer above, is what's called for, because an original is not trivial to forge. In any event, if you were taken to jail, it would (in the police's view) not be a mistake at all, but a rational response to a traveler who isn't following the rules.

Comment: @abdul if you're caught with only a photocopy it'll be likely no different than if you were caught with nothing at all as the photocopy is not a valid ID so will be ignored. At best it will be used to get the number and enter that into a system to check if it matches a real one, in which case you might be given some more time to supply the real one, as well as a fine for illegally copying a government document (my passport has a prohibition on making copies except for very specific purposes printed on it, and those purposes are only those where the law requires a copy to be made).

Comment: @abdul the issuing authority may confirm that the number belongs to a real ID, and maybe whether the holder of that ID has outstanding criminal charges, but that's it. You still have to supply the real ID. And that goes not just for foreigners but locals as well. If you get caught here without ID the police can and likely will detain you until someone brings your ID to them, or they may offer to take you home under guard so you can pick it up yourself. You're then going to be fined for not having your ID on you. And yes, that's in the EU.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica when I said "unless they make a mistake", I meant if the issuing authority makes a mistake and says the number does not belong to a real ID while it really does.

Comment: Yeah ok I understand and I won't question, but I was asking because the process seems unnecessary since one can have their identity verified even by voice, at least to a national level.

Comment: *Just to clarify, EU countries are not in the habit of arresting people just because they don't have ID on them* Not arrest exactly but The Netherlands issues a [couple of tens of thousands fines of year under this pretense](https://nos.nl/artikel/2074411-meer-boetes-voor-niet-tonen-identiteitsbewijs.html).

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not acceptable.

Besides the police, what's the point?

How are you travelling? Most airplanes, some trains, checking in hotels, renting a car: they all require some form of identification. For crossing borders too, and even for Schengen borders you might need some official ID.  If you lose your credit card, you might use your ID for getting money through Western Union or similar services.

Take your ID with you, and leave the passport at a safe location. If you want to reduce the chances of losing the ID use a travel belt, hidden pocket or neck pouch.

Answer (score 1):

There is no EU resident/citizen database authorities could use to double-check your data and no EU-wide rule regulating this matter. As often, what the EU mandates is that other EU citizens are treated on a par with citizens. It's still  up to the country to regulate police checks, registration and identification requirements as they like.

Depending on the jurisdiction, holding or carrying government sanctioned ID might or might not be mandatory and the likelihood of a check varies widely. You might also end up needing some identification document following other interaction with the police (accident, etc.) There is at least one country (the Netherlands), where not carrying ID is a (minor) criminal offense, punishable by a fine.

The downstream risks for you as an EU citizen are limited (you won't be found guilty of illegal stay, deported or banned from reentering the Schengen area or anything like that) but without any ID document, you first need to establish that you are in fact an EU citizen. I have heard of several cases of citizens being retained and put through the process leading towards a removal. Even if the mistake was ultimately cleared up, it would result in a few extremely unpleasant days/hours.

That's one of the reasons I suspect the photocopy might in fact be useful. In practice, even when the police insists that ID is mandatory (possibly illegally), if they are convinced you are an EU citizen, doing something about the lack of ID is just a burden. Lots of paperwork for something that's not a crime, won't result in a valued outcome in their performance statistics, etc. They might seize on the copy to let you go with a verbal warning. Something similar happened to members of my family (with non-official non-photo ID like credit cards).

Comment: Removal of what???

Comment: @abdul Of the country, which could be the ultimate outcome if you were found not to be an (EU) citizen and to have no claim to be in the country. That's one of the reasons ID are being checked in some area.

Comment: The downvote on this answer is baffling.  Of course a photocopy does not satisfy a legal requirement to carry ID.  Of course a photocopy could serve to (help) convince police that the person is an EU citizen.  Of course a police officer might decide to let the person go with a warning.  Or not: police behavior varies widely.  But of the small number of incidents where an ID is requested, some proportion will go more smoothly if there's a photocopy.  So this answer is correct: a photocopy might be useful.

Comment: But also PR of any EU country can travel across Europe, hence a certificate of residence may be needed only, and provided that these certificates are issued only one has either a PR card or a temporary permit, then it means that one could even travel with a photocopy of the residence certificate (not permit), hence me as well.

Comment: @abdul PR of an EU country does not necessarily have the right to travel to other EU countries.  A permanent resident of France, for example, who is a citizen of Nigeria, requires a visa to enter Ireland.

Comment: @abdul As I wrote, there are no EU rules about this. Even if a third-country permanent resident is allowed to enter a specific EU country, that country is still completely free to impose ID requirements and to refuse anything else than a passport or EU national ID card. This is an entirely different matter.

Comment: @phoog I meant mostly it applies, my father went from Italy to Belgium with his PR, and he's a Moroccan national. Of course it doesn't apply for Ireland, since the latter is not in the Schengen Area.

Comment: I wrongly interchange EU with Schengen Area sometimes out of distraction, not unawareness.

Comment: @abdul anyone with a Schengen residence permit, permanent or otherwise, can travel around the Schengen area.  But some Schengen countries have an ID requirement for which the residence permit is not sufficient, even if it's the original.  For example, a US citizen who resides in Germany with a German residence permit needs a US passport to satisfy the Dutch identification law.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, most of Schengen countries require a passport along with the PR, nevertheless it still entails that Schengen PRs can travel across the Schengen area.

Comment: @abdul right.  But if you live in Kleve or some other border town with a residence permit and you're on your way home from work, and you decide you want to pop over to the Netherlands to have dinner in some restaurant you know there, legally speaking you have to go home first and pick up your passport before you go. This is true whether you're Canadian or Cambodian or even from an EU country with no ID cards.  An Italian in this situation, however, needs only a national ID card, both for residence in Germany and for visiting the Netherlands.

Comment: @phoog My last comment was about non-EU citizens, obviously this situation for a EU citizen living in an other country who's also in the EU would be nothing but rendundant in this case, he can either only his national ID or his PR as well, if it can be issued at him.

Comment: @abdul No, an EU citizen crossing over to the Netherlands could *not* use a residence document for that. Bringing this up just adds confusion, we are talking about rules that apply even to the country's own citizens, this is only indirectly related to freedom of movement, immigration law or the right to be in the country. Under Dutch law, you need a specific document to establish your identity, which does *not* include residence permits from other Schengen countries. That's separate from any document establishing your right to enter the country (which this residence permit can provide).